# Set a fix background image for all my pages in PDF iText ASP C#

Tags: asp.net, background-image, itext

On Button Click, I generate 4 pages on my PDF, i added this image to provide a background image

```
        string imageFilePath = parent + "/Images/bg_image.jpg";
        iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFilePath);
        jpg.ScaleToFit(1700, 1000);
        jpg.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING;
        jpg.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
        document.Add(jpg);
```

It works only with 1 page, but when i generate a PDF that contains many records and have several pages, the bg image is only at the last page. I want to apply the background image to all of the pages.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that the background is added only once, because you're adding it only once.

If you want to add content to every page, you should not do that *manually* because you don't know when a new page will be created by iText. Instead you should use a page event. This is explained in [Chapter 5 of my book](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=5) (for the C# version of the examples, see http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C05 ).

A nice example can be found in the [Stationery](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=114) example in chapter 6: [Stationery.cs](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter06/Stationery.cs)

The idea is to create an implementation of the `PdfPageEvent` interface, for instance by extending the `PdfPageEventHelper` class and overriding the `OnEndPage()` method:

```
class TemplateHelper : PdfPageEventHelper {
    private Stationery instance;
    public TemplateHelper() { }
    public TemplateHelper(Stationery instance) { 
        this.instance = instance;
    }
    /**
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onEndPage(
     *      com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document)
     */
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        writer.DirectContentUnder.AddTemplate(instance.page, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

In this case, we add a `PdfTemplate`, but it is very easy to add an `Image` replacing the `Stationery` instance with an `Image` instance and replacing the `AddTemplate()` method with the `AddImage()` method.

Once you have an instance of your custom page event, you need to declare it to the `PdfWriter` instance:

```
writer.PageEvent = new TemplateHelper(this);
```

From that moment on, your `OnEndPage()` method will be executed each time a page is finalized.

**Warning:** as documented you *shall not* use the `OnStartPage()` method to add content in a page event!

**Update:**

The final result would look more or less like this:

```
class ImageBackgroundHelper : PdfPageEventHelper {
    private Image img;
    public ImageBackgroundHelper(Image img) { 
        this.img = img;
    }
    /**
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onEndPage(
     *      com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document)
     */
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        writer.DirectContentUnder.AddImage(img);
    }
}
```

Now you can use this event like this:

```
string imageFilePath = parent + "/Images/bg_image.jpg";
iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFilePath);
jpg.ScaleToFit(1700, 1000);
jpg.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
writer.PageEvent = new ImageBackgroundHelper(jpg);
```

Note that 1700 and 1000 seems quite big. Are you sure those are the dimensions of your page?

Comment: i keep on having error that says "ImageBackgroundHelper does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument" for the code         writer.PageEvent = new ImageBackgroundHelper(jpg);

Comment: I can clearly see the constructor: `public ImageBackgroundHelper(Image img) { 
        this.img = img;
    }` Please don't troll StackOverflow!