# A watermark image and table in itext - Edited

Tags: itext, watermark, pdfptable

I want to insert a table over a watermark image. I have followed many steps but all help in writing over the image not inserting a table.

Edit:
the image should be inserted in each page in the pdf document. i want to write over it using **pdfdTable**. all searches describe how to write a text over a watermark.

e.g:
`document.add(getWatermarkedImage(cb, img, "some text"));`

if i added the pdfdtable to the document as document.add(table); it wont be over the image. it will inserted above the image.

as this is my table:

```
outerCell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(" header 1"));
outerCell.setColspan(70);
outerCell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
outerTable.addCell(outerCell);
```

how could i insert this outertable above the watermark

Comment: This question should be closed because it's not clear: are you creating a document from scratch, or are you adding a watermark to an existing document? Are you using iText 5 or are you using iText 7. You claim that you *have followed many steps*, but why would anyone believe you if you don't show us what you've tried. Have you even read the documentation. There are literally a dozen [examples about watermarks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/search/node/watermark) on the official web site. Surely one of these examples can help you? If not, why not?

Comment: If you are creating a document from scratch, you need to read the answer to [How to add a watermark to a page with an opaque image?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-watermark-page-opaque-image) If you're adding a watermark to an existing document, you need [How to watermark PDFs using text or images?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-watermark-pdfs-using-text-or-images) I'd close the question by marking it as a duplicate of a [question that explains how to make images transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241731/), but that answer never got a vote.

Comment: Show us all the many steps you followed and someone (not me) will step in to tell you what you need to change. Without your code, no answer.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question and admitting that you didn't read the documentation. Next time, please read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds wrong. It's as if you want to add an image watermark to a document, which is adequately explained in many other questions such as [Set a fix background image for all my pages in PDF iText ASP C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688288/set-a-fix-background-image-for-all-my-pages-in-pdf-itext-asp-c-sharp) and [How can I add an image to all pages of my PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908651/add-an-image-in-all-pages-of-pdf) (These answers are about C# questions, but the [official web site](https://developers.itextpdf.com/) has many [watermark](https://developers.itextpdf.com/search/node/watermark) and [page event](https://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/page-events) examples.)

Just like [madhesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2894742/madhesh), you confuse the StackOverflow readers, even after you've read my answer to the question [How to add text to an image?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-image) where I wrote:

> This is a good example of a question that is phrased in a way that nobody can answer it correctly. After a lot of back and forth comments, it was finally clear that the OP wanted to add a text watermark to an image. Badly phrase questions can be very frustrating. Please take that in consideration when asking a question. In this case, I gave several wrong answers before it became clear what was actually asked.

You want to add a `PdfPTable` to an `Image` and your knowledge is insufficient to understand and adapt the examples provided with the answers to questions such as [How to add text to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814958/pdf-vertical-postion-method-gives-the-next-page-position-instead-of-current-page) and [Draw Lines on Image in PDF using ItextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29561417/draw-lines-on-image-in-pdf-using-itextsharp).

What you're asking is extremely simple though.

The `getWatermarkedImage()` method that you mention looks like this:

```
public Image getWatermarkedImage(PdfContentByte cb, Image img) throws DocumentException {
    float width = img.getScaledWidth();
    float height = img.getScaledHeight();
    PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(width, height);
    template.addImage(img, width, 0, 0, height, 0, 0);
    template.saveState();
    template.setColorStroke(BaseColor.GREEN);
    template.setLineWidth(3);
    template.moveTo(width * .25f, height * .25f);
    template.lineTo(width * .75f, height * .75f);
    template.moveTo(width * .25f, height * .75f);
    template.lineTo(width * .25f, height * .25f);
    template.stroke();
    template.setColorStroke(BaseColor.WHITE);
    template.ellipse(0, 0, width, height);
    template.stroke();
    template.restoreState();
    return Image.getInstance(template);
}
```

This is the example taken from the answer to the question [How to draw lines on an image?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-draw-lines-image)

You don't want to draw lines, so you can remove all the code that draws lines:

```
public Image getWatermarkedImage(PdfContentByte cb, Image img) throws DocumentException {
    float width = img.getScaledWidth();
    float height = img.getScaledHeight();
    PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(width, height);
    template.addImage(img, width, 0, 0, height, 0, 0);
    // removed the code that draws lines
    return Image.getInstance(template);
}
```

Instead of lines, you want to draw a `PdfPTable`, so we add some code where it says `// removed the code that draws lines`. As documented, adding a table at an absolute position is done with the [`writeSelectedRows()`](https://developers.itextpdf.com/search/node/writeselectedrows) method:

```
public Image getWatermarkedImage(PdfContentByte cb, Image img) throws DocumentException {
    float width = img.getScaledWidth();
    float height = img.getScaledHeight();
    PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(width, height);
    template.addImage(img, width, 0, 0, height, 0, 0);
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setTotalWidth(width);
    table.getDefaultCell().setBorderColor(BaseColor.Yellow);
    table.addCell("Test1");
    table.addCell("Test2");
    table.addCell("Test3");
    table.addCell("Test4");
    table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, height, template);
    return Image.getInstance(template);
}
```

I adapted one of the many examples in the official documentation (see [WatermarkedImages5](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/image-examples-itext5/adding-watermarks-images#1958-watermarkedimages5.java)), and this is the result:

[image]

All the functionality you needed to achieve this was available in the documentation. Please read that documentation before you post another question.