# Setting a background on iText PDF

Tags: java, image, pdf, background, itext

My problem is that I need to add a background to an iText PDF file.
The background should fill the whole page and is an image.

Please answer quickly.
Thanks for your help

Here is the code and I want to place an image in the background.

[image]
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIQA1.png)

```
        Document document = new Document();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        PdfPCell Left = new PdfPCell();
        Left.setBorder(0);
        Left.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        PdfPCell Right = new PdfPCell();
        Right.setBorder(0);
        Right.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new 
        FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\jensh\\Desktop\\QuizErgebnis.pdf"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        document.open();
        com.itextpdf.text.Font font = 
        FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 16, BaseColor.BLACK);

        try {
            com.itextpdf.text.Image image = 
        com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance("bg.jpg");
        } catch (BadElementException | IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        try {
            Paragraph H1 = new Paragraph("ZERTIFIKAT", font);
            H1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            H1.setSpacingAfter(30);
    
            document.add(H1);
            table.addCell(Left);
            table.addCell(Right);
            document.add(table);

        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        document.close();
```

Comment: if you need it quickly, here's the documentation around background: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/search?q=background&max=500

Comment: I tried but it doesn´t work

Comment: can you add to your original post what you tried (a code sample)?

Comment: Document document = new Document();
   
   try {
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("Quiz.pdf"));
   } catch (FileNotFoundException | DocumentException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
   }

         document.open();
   
         //create image...

Comment: can you update the initial question and add the whole code? I can't see on the document what attempt you did to get the background working. Also, it seems you are using iText5 (my link was for iText7). Here is the link for 5 https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/search?q=background&max=500&s=IT5KB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a fix background image for all my pages in PDF iText ASP C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688288/set-a-fix-background-image-for-all-my-pages-in-pdf-itext-asp-c-sharp)

Comment: *"I tried but it doesn´t work"* - that is a problem decrypting missing too much detail.

Comment: the commands are marked red but I can't import classes etc

Comment: which jars are you using/can you share your build system configuration (maven/gradle/ant/wtv)?

Comment: I am using iText 5.0.1

Comment: iText 5.0.1 is ancient. Your code should work nonetheless but you should definitively update.

Comment: please also show your import lines, there might be an issue with them.

Comment: added it to the question

Comment: There is no `import` line for the `Image` class you use.  Thus, it isn't found. Simply add the applicable `Image` import statement.

Comment: The problem is that there isn´t an import statement

Comment: Your latest screen shot shows that your ide thinks `Image` is `java.awt.Image` but your code needs the `Image` class of iText which IIRC is `com.itextpdf.text.Image`.

Comment: Here is a video. It does not work

https://1drv.ms/v/s!AgSdYq9Muoc0gpoDGjUfi9wmr1iOnQ?e=eFUeyb